# Exporting tabs from TuxGuitar to Lilypond

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond, tuxguitar

I am writing tabs from TuxGuitar and then export it to lilypond (Because I find it easier to do it in TuxGuitar). Here before exporting it to lilypond everything seems nice:
[image]

But when I export and engrave it with lilypond it seems like this:
[image]
As it is seen note positions are not correct. How can I fix this? Is it about TuxGuitar or lilypond? Or what kind of program should I use to write tabs and export it to lilypond easier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that TuxGuitar fails to set the proper clef.

Just find the music in the lilypond file and put `\clef "G_8"` in front of it. That will do the trick.

---

**Explanation:** As Tom_C correctly points out, guitar is written in treble clef but one octave higher than it actually sounds. TuxGuitar apparently just sets a treble clef (or no clef at all, which amounts to the same). The systemic way to handle that is to use a treble clef with a small 8 under it (which says that everything has in fact to be played one octave lower). That's the clef that Lilypond knows under the name of `G_8` (or `treble_8`).

Setting the proper clef will also make sure that Lilypond will both "know internally" the correct notes and typeset them correctly, too. You could just transpose everything an octave higher; however, if you for instance played the MIDI generated by Lilypond, it would also sound an octave higher than it should.

Comment: Neat! I was sure that someone with good LP skills would have a nice way to do that!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably linked to : [why is guitar music written one octave higher?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/101432/why-is-guitar-music-written-one-octave-higher)

An easy fix would be to transpose everything 12 half tones higher but not sure if it easier in Tux or Lilypond...